# Excel logical statement for implication. How to realize?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: implication logical sheet]

How can I use implication in Excel formulas? Just like other Excel logical functions for Boolean calcs?
The same question for OpenOffice and Google sheets as well.

Comment: Please, edit and *embed* the image instead.

Answer (score 1):

=OR(NOT(x1), x2)
A -> B <=> ¬ A ∨ B

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided truth-table, using True and False...

`=NOT(AND(x1==True,x2==False))`

What it does; AND() creates a "True" when (x1 is True) AND (x2 is False) both at the same time.
NOT() reverses this, so leaving "False" as result instead,
the AND()  will leave a False in all other cases - reversed to True by NOT().

Should be the exact same regardless of which spreadsheet you use.

Comment: I posted my solution. It is not a perfect but works. Thanks

Comment: Read wiki about DNF & CNF in Boolean was useful for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: my realization of logical implication in excel]
=IF(A2+B2=0;1; IF(AND(A2=0;B2=1);1; IF(AND(A2;B2);1;0)))"
I use localized russian excel so ru version  `=ЕСЛИ(A2+B2=0;1;ЕСЛИ(И(A2=0;B2=1);1;ЕСЛИ(И(A2;B2);1;0)))`